# Closing Paths in Illusstrator pen tool

Tags: adobe-illustrator, tools, pen-tool

Hello I have a question?

I'm using the pen tool and I have a lot lines alternating my artboard how would I close the paths the alternating lines that I have drawn in Illustrator.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by 'alternating'. Please share an image of your project so that we can help you.

Answer (score 0):

Paths don't need to always be closed.

Please include a snapshot of what you've got and maybe a sketch of what you're trying to achieve so the community can better assist you.